# Multiple Update from Select Where Exists in SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql-server-2008

I'm trying to rewrite this Oracle query for SQL Server 2008:

```
UPDATE "LOAD"."UNITS_OF_MEASURE" 
SET ("UOM_DESC", "UOM_SYMBOL", "UOM_MUL_FACTOR", "UOM_ADD_FACTOR", "UOM_DEC_PLACE", "UOM_REFERENCE", "UOM_SUBTYPE_ID") =
                 ( SELECT "UOM_DESC", "UOM_SYMBOL", "UOM_MUL_FACTOR", "UOM_ADD_FACTOR", "UOM_DEC_PLACE", 0 AS "UOM_REFERENCE", NULL AS "UOM_SUBTYPE_ID"
                    FROM ( SELECT DISTINCT "UOM_TYPE_ID", "UOM_CODE", "UOM_DESC", "UOM_SYMBOL", "UOM_MUL_FACTOR", "UOM_ADD_FACTOR", "UOM_DEC_PLACE"
                            FROM "LOAD"."LOADER_UNITS_OF_MEASURE"
                            INNER JOIN "LOAD"."UOM_TYPES" ON ("UOM_TYPES"."UOM_TYPE_CODE"="LOADER_UNITS_OF_MEASURE"."UOM_TYPE_CODE")
                         ) SELECTION
                    WHERE ("SELECTION"."UOM_TYPE_ID"="UNITS_OF_MEASURE"."UOM_TYPE_ID")
                    AND ("SELECTION"."UOM_CODE"="UNITS_OF_MEASURE"."UOM_CODE")
                )
WHERE EXISTS  ( SELECT "UOM_DESC", "UOM_SYMBOL", "UOM_MUL_FACTOR", "UOM_ADD_FACTOR", "UOM_DEC_PLACE", 0 AS "UOM_REFERENCE", NULL AS "UOM_SUBTYPE_ID"
                  FROM ( SELECT DISTINCT "UOM_TYPE_ID", "UOM_CODE", "UOM_DESC", "UOM_SYMBOL", "UOM_MUL_FACTOR", "UOM_ADD_FACTOR", "UOM_DEC_PLACE"
                          FROM "LOAD"."LOADER_UNITS_OF_MEASURE"
                          INNER JOIN "LOAD"."UOM_TYPES" ON ("UOM_TYPES"."UOM_TYPE_CODE"="LOADER_UNITS_OF_MEASURE"."UOM_TYPE_CODE")
                        ) SELECTION
                 WHERE ("SELECTION"."UOM_TYPE_ID"="UNITS_OF_MEASURE"."UOM_TYPE_ID")
                 AND ("SELECTION"."UOM_CODE"="UNITS_OF_MEASURE"."UOM_CODE")
)
```

The inner `SELECT` query should remain the same, since the query is automatically composed by a DBMS-indipendent query-builder layer.

I tried, among others, the following syntax:

```
UPDATE "LOAD"."UNITS_OF_MEASURE" 
SET "UOM_DESC" = i."UOM_DESC", "UOM_SYMBOL" = i."UOM_SYMBOL", "UOM_MUL_FACTOR" = i."UOM_MUL_FACTOR", "UOM_ADD_FACTOR" = i."UOM_ADD_FACTOR", "UOM_DEC_PLACE" = i."UOM_DEC_PLACE",
     "UOM_REFERENCE" = 0, "UOM_SUBTYPE_ID" = NULL FROM
                 ( SELECT "UOM_DESC", "UOM_SYMBOL", "UOM_MUL_FACTOR", "UOM_ADD_FACTOR", "UOM_DEC_PLACE", 0 AS "UOM_REFERENCE", NULL AS "UOM_SUBTYPE_ID"
                    FROM ( SELECT DISTINCT "UOM_TYPE_ID", "UOM_CODE", "UOM_DESC", "UOM_SYMBOL", "UOM_MUL_FACTOR", "UOM_ADD_FACTOR", "UOM_DEC_PLACE"
                            FROM "LOAD"."LOADER_UNITS_OF_MEASURE"
                            INNER JOIN "LOAD"."UOM_TYPES" ON ("UOM_TYPES"."UOM_TYPE_CODE"="LOADER_UNITS_OF_MEASURE"."UOM_TYPE_CODE")
                         ) SELECTION
                    WHERE ("SELECTION"."UOM_TYPE_ID"="UNITS_OF_MEASURE"."UOM_TYPE_ID")
                    AND ("SELECTION"."UOM_CODE"="UNITS_OF_MEASURE"."UOM_CODE")
                )i
WHERE EXISTS ( SELECT "UOM_DESC", "UOM_SYMBOL", "UOM_MUL_FACTOR", "UOM_ADD_FACTOR", "UOM_DEC_PLACE", 0 AS "UOM_REFERENCE", NULL AS "UOM_SUBTYPE_ID"
                  FROM ( SELECT DISTINCT "UOM_TYPE_ID", "UOM_CODE", "UOM_DESC", "UOM_SYMBOL", "UOM_MUL_FACTOR", "UOM_ADD_FACTOR", "UOM_DEC_PLACE"
                          FROM "LOAD"."LOADER_UNITS_OF_MEASURE"
                          INNER JOIN "LOAD"."UOM_TYPES" ON ("UOM_TYPES"."UOM_TYPE_CODE"="LOADER_UNITS_OF_MEASURE"."UOM_TYPE_CODE")
                        ) SELECTION
                 WHERE ("SELECTION"."UOM_TYPE_ID"="UNITS_OF_MEASURE"."UOM_TYPE_ID")
                 AND ("SELECTION"."UOM_CODE"="UNITS_OF_MEASURE"."UOM_CODE")
)
```

but unfortunately `"UNITS_OF_MEASURE"."UOM_TYPE_ID"` and `"UNITS_OF_MEASURE"."UOM_CODE"` on line 9-10 cannot be resolved.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Basically this looks as if you were correlating a derived table with the outer table (the target of the UPDATE), as opposed to joining it to the latter. This doesn't work in Transact-SQL (and I also doubt if this would work in Oracle, as a matter of fact).

However, you can use the `UPDATE...FROM` syntax: just get rid of the middle-tier SELECT and use the inner-most SELECT as a derived table to join to `UNITS_OF_MEASURE`, i.e. like this:

```
UPDATE "LOAD"."UNITS_OF_MEASURE" 
SET "UOM_DESC" = "SELECTION"."UOM_DESC",
    "UOM_SYMBOL" = "SELECTION"."UOM_SYMBOL",
    "UOM_MUL_FACTOR" = "SELECTION"."UOM_MUL_FACTOR",
    "UOM_ADD_FACTOR" = "SELECTION"."UOM_ADD_FACTOR",
    "UOM_DEC_PLACE" = "SELECTION"."UOM_DEC_PLACE",
    "UOM_REFERENCE" = 0,
    "UOM_SUBTYPE_ID" = NULL
FROM ( SELECT DISTINCT "UOM_TYPE_ID", "UOM_CODE", "UOM_DESC", "UOM_SYMBOL",
                       "UOM_MUL_FACTOR", "UOM_ADD_FACTOR", "UOM_DEC_PLACE"
       FROM "LOAD"."LOADER_UNITS_OF_MEASURE"
       INNER JOIN "LOAD"."UOM_TYPES" ON ("UOM_TYPES"."UOM_TYPE_CODE"="LOADER_UNITS_OF_MEASURE"."UOM_TYPE_CODE")
     ) SELECTION
WHERE ("SELECTION"."UOM_TYPE_ID"="UNITS_OF_MEASURE"."UOM_TYPE_ID")
  AND ("SELECTION"."UOM_CODE"="UNITS_OF_MEASURE"."UOM_CODE")
;
```

This would join the `SELECTION` derived table to `"LOAD"."UNITS_OF_MEASURE"` and use the derived table's data to update the other table's columns.

Comment: Thanks! This works, actually I found the same solution on my own just before your post.